# why is setOnShowListener never called?

Tags: android

Here is my code:

```
mDialog.show();
mDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
  @Override
  public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    //some code
  }
});
```

The breakpoints shows that `//some code` is never called. Can you help me understand what is happening ?

It's API 8 and above (supported by my app)

Comment: is the call to `show()` before the listener registration?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I could be wrong but you should set the listener before you call `show()` on the Dialog.

Comment: How can I dismiss the progress bar. When I use mDialog.Dismiss inside the override method, it won't be shown at all.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
mDialog.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
  @Override
  public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
    //some code

  }
});

mDialog.show();
```

This way you ensure that the listener is registered before the dialog is shown.

Answer (score 0):

Declare and initialize AlertDialogBuilder:

```
   final AlertDialog.Builder dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
```

set dialog parameters like:

alert buttons ( Positive, Negative or Neutral ),

setTitle, setIcon..

> not call here method - show() - read second answer, 2 posts up from my answer

Then,

Create new Alert dialog, who use first dialog with the assigned parameters:

```
   final AlertDialog alert=dialog.create();
```

and set OnShowListener, ex:

```
   alert.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                                Button button = alert.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE); 

                                Drawable drawable = getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(
                                        R.drawable.error);


                                drawable.setBounds((int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 0.5),
                                        0, (int) (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * 1.5),
                                        drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
                                button.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
                            }
                        });
```

> and final step is: alert.show();

Comment: You have some strange formatting here. Why are you using `>` to quote something that is not a quotation? And should `dialog.setAdapter(..)` be part of the code block before it? Also, I'm not sure you are answering the question.

Comment: dialog.setAdapter(..) is part of other adapter my example is for show dialog on click on ListView item. I have 2 adapter.  I use setListAdapter(adapter); after i call alert.show i will edit the post order to avoid confusion. What is "Why are you using > to quote something that is not a quotation? "  i don't understand question??

Comment: Do you see the lines that are rendered with a yellow background? To have that effect you must put a `>` character at the beginning of those lines. This should be used to quote text from other sources, but this is not what you are doing. And I don't understand what you are trying to say from "set the buttons" to "read 2 posts up".

Comment: Aha i understand you. I say to set parameter on alert dialog like,  (setPositiveButton, setNegativeButton, setNeutralButton, setTitle, setIcon...) after declaring AlertDialog.Builder dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()). After you add the flowing parameters, not call here method show() and i think on second answer, two posts up from my post.

Comment: Not working , I tested